# Using the Title in Navigation Bar for a page status

Tags: navigation, android, ios, mobile-application, app

I'm designing an app on iOS & Android. My client wants the title in the Navigation Bar/App Bar to be a status rather than a page title.
Instead of "Registration" he wants to switch between "Registration closed" and "Register now". I'm having my doubts.

Would you allow it?
It seems that space is meant for the title only, but in no guidelines it says specifically this is ok or not. 
But I feel any status message is better set in the content area, where it also can be highlighted properly. And I assume users don't really pay much attention to those titles at first.

What are your thoughts on this? 
Any good arguments for or against are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common convention for the text in the middle of a navigation bar is indeed the title of the page the user is currently on (or in some cases the app logo).

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Status' are commonly used in and around this; to the left, right of the bar or:
- in the content/body of the app
- in some form of a notification
- a status strip, pop up or modal
- a contextual notification

I would argue against what the client is asking for, there are countless examples of this (all of which you could put to the client) where the expected behaviour is that what you are describing is a title.

Also Registration Closed may even deter users from actually using, exploring or indeed coming back to register on the app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and examples! And your last argument is gold! I did not think of that.